# How to send large data on network using udp protocol?

Tags: c++, c, networking, posix

User space can call send and only send MTU size packets.
This will force multiple calls to send but will avoid IP fragmentation.
But multiple calls to send will force multiple user/kernel context switch.

The other way is that user space can send big packets (may be N*MTU size) and that will cause N IP fragments, but will decrease user/kernel context switch.

On the other hand, IP fragments can slow down the network path too, as all the routers need to accumulate the packet before routing forward.

After my googling research, I came to conclusion that using iovec with readv/writev and sending MTU size is possibly a way to go as it will address both the concerns about context switch and IP fragmentation.

I will appreciate any deep insight and opinion on this.

Comment: "_User space can call send and only send MTU size packets._" That depends on the transport protocol used. For example, you can give TCP large blocks of data to send, and it will segment the data into MSS sized segments and send it for you. TCP segmentation is _not_ IP fragmentation.

Comment: @RonMaupin  You are right. TCP does it as part of protocol as it tries to get the MTU of link. The above problem is mainly due to UDP. I have updated my question.

Comment: normally, you would step through your buffer one MTU at a time, and send. But, udp doesn't guarantee order or success. So, the sender may need to retry, and the receiver may need to reorder the received packets.

Comment: Also, if you wish to avoid IP fragmentation altogether, you need to perform PMTUD (RFC 1191 for IPv4) before sending anything.